# Framework for a server application (preferably, using BOOST C++)

Tags: c++, boost

I am thinking of writing a server application - along the lines of mySQL or Apache.

The main requirements are:

1. Clients will communicate with the server via TCP/IP (sockets)
2. The server will spawn a new child process to handle requests (ala Apache)

Ideally, I would like to use the BOOST libraries rather than attempt to reinvent my own. There must be code somewhere that does most of what I am trying to do - so I can use it (or atleast part of it as my starting point) can anyone point me to a useful link?

In the (hopefully unlikely) event that there is no code I can use as a starting point, can someone point out the most appropriate BOOST libraries to use - and a general guideline on how to proceeed.

My main worry is how to know when one of the children has crashed. AFAIK, there are two ways of doing this:

1. Using heartbeats between the parent and children (this quickly becomes messy, and introduces more things that could go wrong)
2. Somehow wrap the spawning of the process with a timeout parameter - but this is a dumb approach, because if a child is carrying out time intensive work, the parent may incorrectly think that the child has died

What is the best practises of making the parent aware that a child has died?

**[Edit]**

BTW, I am developing/running/deploying on Linux

Comment: I don't know what system you are using, but in Posix systems, parent receives a signal when the child terminates for whatever reason. And, BTW, forking child processes for each connection is not state of the art for a very long time already.

Comment: You might want to look into Node.js: http://nodejs.org/. It's implemented on top of Google V8 JavaScript engine. I'd say it looks very promising! Node.js seems to have extremely good response times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can say for sure that [Pion](http://www.pion.org/projects) is your only stable option.
I have never used it but I intend to, and the API looks very clean.

As for the Boost libraries you would need:

- Boost.Asio
- Boost.Threading
- Boost.Spirit (or something similar to parse the HTTP protocol)
- Boost.IPC

Comment: Pion does indeed, look very promising indeed

Comment: what's Boost.IPC? I can find it on boost site. I may indeed need an IPC framework

Answer (score 4):

On what platform (Windows/Linux/both)? Processes on Windows are considered more heavy-weight than on Linux, so you may indeed consider threads.

Also, I think it is better (like Apache does) not to spawn a process for each request but to have a process pool, so you save the cost of creating a process, especially on Windows.

If you are on Linux, can `waitpid()` be useful for you? You can use it in the non-blocking mode to check recurrently with some interval whether one of the child processes terminated

Answer (score 1):

What about using threads (which are supported by Boost) rather than forking the process? This would allow you to make queries about the state of a child and, imho, threads are simpler to handle than forking.

Comment: I want to avoid using threads for two reasons: 1. Debugging can MT apps can easily end up being a TOTAL nightmare (at least in my experience).  2. Robustness: I don't want a single child terminating unexpectedly to crash the server.

Comment: IMO you will have a hard time get past threads here. Spawning processes for each connection won't scale. Avoid shared state and your MT won't bother you. The idea of a process pool (like davka suggest) is a very reasonable one.

Comment: Actually, I like the idea of a process pool (now why didn't I think of that!)

Answer (score 1):

Generally Boost.Asio is good point to begin with.

But several points to be aware of:

1. Boost.Asio is very good library but it is not very fork aware, so don't try to share Asio
   event loop between several fork processes - this would not work (i.e. - if `boost::asio::io_service` was created before fork - don't use it in more then one process after it)

   Also it does not allow you to release file handler from `boost::asio::XX::socket` 
   so only way is to call dup and then pass it to child process.

   But to be honest? I don't think you'll find any network event loop library that is
   fork aware (maybe with exception of CppCMS's booster.aio that I had written
   to be fork aware by myself).
2. Waiting for children is quite simple you can define a signal handler with `sigaction`
   on `SIGCHLD` signal that is send then child crashes or exits. 
   So all you need to do is handle this signal and in main loop call waitpid when such
   signal received.

   With asio you can use "self-pipe" trick to wake the loop from sleep from signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at [CPPCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net). It might already fit your needs.

Now, as pointed by others, boost::asio is a good starting point but is really the basics of the task.

Maybe you'll be more interested in the works being done about server-code based on boost::asio : [cpp-netlib](https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib) (that is made to be submitted in boost once done) [The author's blog](http://cplusplus-soup.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I've made an FOSS library for creating C++ applications in a modular way. It's hosted at

https://github.com/chilabot/chila

here's my blog: http://chilatools.blogspot.com/view/sidebar

It's specially suited for generic server creation (that was my motivation for constructing it), but I think it can be used for any kind of application.

The part that has to be deployed with the final binary is LGPL, so it can be used with commercial applications.